# My ANTLR3 tree grammar never matches a particular pattern that is very similar to one that does get matched

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I am working on my own language application which is heavily based on the Cymbol grammar from the Language Implementation Patterns book.  I have been using ANTLRworks to develop my grammars, and then implementing the full application in Java using Eclipse.  As part of my grammar, I have these two rules:

```
varDeclaration
  :  'var' ID 'is' dataType (':=' expr )? ';'
     -> ^('var' ^(NAME ID) ^(VARTYPE dataType) ^(VALUE expr)?)
  ;
constantDeclaration
  :  'const' ID 'is' dataType ':=' expr ';'
     -> ^('const' ^(NAME ID) ^(VARTYPE dataType) ^(VALUE expr))
  ;
```

After running the parser and printing the generated AST, the output for both of these appears to be correct.

I then run a symbol definition tree matcher (with filter-true) to build a symbol table.  Apart from entering each function/block/etc. to start new scopes, I also handle the definition of variables and constants in the topdown rule (again, based of the Language Implementation Patterns book), as below:

```
topdown
  :  varDeclaration
  |  constDeclaration
  | ...
  ;

varDeclaration
  :  ^('var' ^(NAME ID) .*) //^(VAR ^(NAME ID) .*) Rewrote this for clarity of example
     {
        System.out.println("In a variable declaration");
     }
  ;

constDeclaration
  :  ^('const' ^(NAME ID) .*)
     {
        System.out.println("Const definition");
     }
  ;
```

My problem is that only the constDeclaration is matched.  Even though I have varDeclaration in my input (as verified by the AST printout), I never see "In a variable declaration" printed to my console, whereas "Const definition" shows up.

I have tried numerous things to debug/resolve this:

- Made the optional initialization expression of the variable declaration not optional, so that it is grammatically identical to the const declaration except of the keyword.
- Changed the keyword 'var' to something else ('splunge', in this case).
- Changed the match parameters to use specific wildcards (eg. ^(VAR vn=. vt=. vv=.))
- Tried putting the varDeclaration in the bottomup rule.

As you can see, I was getting pretty desperate, as I have no idea why one rule and pattern matches and the other does not.  The only other difference between the variable and constant declarations is that constant declarations can happen within a code block and at the top level (for global consts) whereas variables can only be declared within a code block.  I don't see how this could have any bearing on why a const in a code block will be matched when a var will not.

This code is an example of what is matched incorrectly:

```
function foo(int a) returns (int) {
  const PI is real := 3.14159;  // Recognized
  var r is real;                // Not recognized
  var s is int := 4;            // Not recognized
  const TESTCONST is int := 3;  // Recognized
  // Other code (if statements, for loops) recognized.
}
```

I have been trying to resolve this problem for several days now, but am at my wits end.  What am I missing?

**Additional Information (added 2013 March 20)**

For further clarification, input declarations such as

```
const y is real := 2.4;  // Recognized
var temp is int := 0 ;   // Not recognized
```

produce the following in the AST:

```
(const (NAME y) (VARTYPE (SCALAR (NAME (TYPEID real)))) (VALUE (EXPR 2.4)))
(var (NAME temp) (VARTYPE (SCALAR (NAME (TYPEID int)))) (VALUE (EXPR 0)))
```

The const AST is matched by the above tree grammar, the var AST is not.

Comment: I'm assuming the `';` in the grammar above is a cut/paste error, and the original grammar actually contains `';'`?

Comment: Right you are---I posted this during a break at work, where I only had a copy of  the grammars I had e-mailed to myself, and must have deleted the closing quote when putting in a line break.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your parser, you match the literal `'var'`, but in your tree parser you are looking for `^(VAR ...`. Does your lexer contain the following rule exactly?

```
VAR : 'var';
```

For `constDeclaration` in the tree parser (which you say works), you are using the same literal syntax you used in the parser: `^('const' ...`

Comment: Sorry, that was the result of yet another attempt at debugging on my part.  My lexer does contain the VAR : 'var' mapping, but originally my tree grammar was ^('var' ^(NAME ID)) similar to the const.